# How can I use a named CASE or IF result in the same select or in the where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

In my query I have a `case`. I want to (re-)use the result in the same `SELECT` so I gave it the name `AANTAL`. Unfortunately does this not work as it says the value `AANTAL` does not exist. I also tried to use `AANTAL` in a `WHERE` but this also results in the same problem. It seems that I cannot reuse named "mutations" at all (like an `IF` statement etc.).

As we work on a given infrastructure I cannot say which DB engine we are using except that it's an Oracle database. When I remember correctly, things like this worked on MySQL in another project so I think it's related to Oracle.

How can i re-use results of `CASE` and `IF` in the `SELECT` or `WHERE` of the same query (on our Oracle environmen).

---

Example of the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT KLANT
  ,CASE WHEN SPAAK > WIEL
    THEN 10
    ELSE 5
    END AS AANTAL
  ,AANTAL * 1.1 RESULT
FROM DELTA.FIETS
```

Comment: The only way to do this is to use a subquery: `select * from (<your query>) sq where calculated_column = 'value'`. This works in any DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse an alias of a SQL query in the same level in which it was defined.  This means you will have to repeat the logic.  One way to deal with this in a tidy way would be to use a common table expression:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT KLANT,
           CASE WHEN SPAAK > WIEL THEN 10 ELSE 5 END AS AANTAL
    FROM DELTA.FIETS
)

SELECT KLANT, AANTAL, AANTAL * 1.1 AS RESULT
FROM cte;
```